# Why am I getting unnamed error using moment() in Express?

Tags: express

I'm getting a strange run time error that seems to be related to the `moment()` function, as below:

```
Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
Arguments:
[0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: function now() { [native code] }, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]
Error
    at Function.createFromInputFallback (C:\Users\John\dev\blah\node_modules\moment\moment.js:320:98)
    at configFromInput (C:\Users\John\dev\blah\node_modules\moment\moment.js:2623:19)
    at prepareConfig (C:\Users\John\dev\blah\node_modules\moment\moment.js:2594:13)
    at createFromConfig (C:\Users\John\dev\blah\node_modules\moment\moment.js:2561:44)
    at createLocalOrUTC (C:\Users\John\dev\blah\node_modules\moment\moment.js:2648:16)
    at createLocal (C:\Users\John\dev\blah\node_modules\moment\moment.js:2652:16)
    at hooks (C:\Users\John\dev\blah\node_modules\moment\moment.js:12:29)
    at auth (C:\Users\John\dev\blah\controllers\users_controller.js:77:32)
    at C:\Users\John\dev\blah\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3880:24
    at replenish (C:\Users\John\dev\blah\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1011:17)
    at C:\Users\John\dev\blah\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1016:9
    at eachOfLimit (C:\Users\John\dev\blah\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1041:24)
    at C:\Users\John\dev\blah\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1046:16
    at eachOf (C:\Users\John\dev\blah\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1117:5)
    at _parallel (C:\Users\John\dev\blah\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3879:5)
    at Object.parallelLimit [as parallel] (C:\Users\John\dev\blah\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3962:5)
(node:1772) [DEP0079] DeprecationWarning: Custom inspection function on Objects via .inspect() is deprecated
```

I think the error is coming from the following code in `users_controller.js`:

```
var moment = require('moment');

exports.user_create_get = function(req, res, next) {
    async.parallel({
        personalData: function(callback){
            var personalDataObj = new PersonalData({
                dateOfBirth: moment('1900-01-01'),
                sex: '',
                maritalStatus: ''
            })
        },
        id: function(callback){
            var idObj = new Id({
                dateProvided: moment('1900-01-01'),
                idDoc: ''
            })
        },
        photo: function(callback){
            var photoObj = new Photo({
                dateProvided: moment('1900-01-01'),
                photoDoc: ''
            })
        },
    }, function(err, result){
        if (err) {return next(err);}
        var user = new User({
            personalData: result.personalData,
            idData: [result.id],
            photoData: [result.photo],
        })
        console.log("Sending JSON . . . ");
        res.json(JSON.parse(user));
    })
};
```

I've looked online and I think I'm using moment() properly. I tried formatting the dates as '01/01/1900', '1900-01-01' -- looking at the error description, I'm not even sure the error is related to `moment()`. Also, I don't understand the deprecation warning, and if it's just a warning, why is the code crashing?

Many thanks in advance if any ideas what's causing this error!

Answer (score 3):

Supplying formats fixed the error. I.e., using `moment("1900-01-01","YYYY-MM-DD").format("YYYY MM DD")` eliminated the error.